# Failed to instantiate module ng due to function($provide) is not using explicit annotation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So here's the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($provide) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(%24provide)
    at localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:53360:12
    at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57244:17)
    at injectionArgs (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57971:36)
    at Object.invoke (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:58002:18)
    at runInvokeQueue (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57903:35)
    at localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57912:11
    at forEach (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:53613:20)
    at loadModules (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57893:5)
    at createInjector (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:57815:19)
    at doBootstrap (localhost/build/js/app-vendor.js:55050:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=Error%3A%20%5….com%3A21293%2FWebGui%2Fbuild%2Fjs%2Fapp-vendor.js%3A55050%3A20)
```

Normally you know what to do: search for not annotated function. But:

- I did it and I can't find bug
- I run my code through `ngAnnotate`
- Stack trace says nothing, only angular code
- searched for occurences of `function($provide)` - in vain

I catched the exception thrown and somewhere on the stack trace there's a:

```
var injector = createInjector(modules, config.strictDi);
injector.invoke(['$rootScope', '$rootElement', '$compile', '$injector',
    function bootstrapApply(scope, element, compile, injector) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            element.data('$injector', injector);
            compile(element)(scope);
        });
    }]
);
return injector;
```

and

```
if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
    $inject = [];
    if (fn.length) {
        if (strictDi) {
            if (!isString(name) || !name) {
                name = fn.name || anonFn(fn);
            }
            throw $injectorMinErr('strictdi',
                '{0} is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode', name);
        }
        argDecl = extractArgs(fn);
        forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg) {
            arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name) {
                $inject.push(name);
            });
        });
    }
    fn.$inject = $inject;
}
```

From what I saw in watch window & stack trace it is happening somewhere in the app where `$injector.invoke` is called with function as argument. But I honestly searched through files and I can't find any of this calls.

It is happening for Angular 1.5.8.

Comment: Sometimes ng-annotate needs a little help by adding explicit /*@ngInject*/. This can be the case in ui-router resolvers for instance.

Comment: I know, but still i analyzed code and didn't find any such a places + if that was my regular code, then exception message would have more details and exactly point to my bug

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, and found it was resolved by disabling the Chrome angularjs debugger "Batarang".